# Ошибка "error: ';' expected"

Tags: java, методы

```
public class Kata {
    public static String createPhoneNumber(int[] numbers) {
        public int Int_to_str(int i) {
            return Integer.toString(numbers[i]);
        }
        return "(" + Int_to_str(0) + Int_to_str(1) + Int_to_str(2) + ") " + 
                Int_to_str(3) + Int_to_str(4) + Int_to_str(5) + "-" + 
                Int_to_str(6) + Int_to_str(7) + Int_to_str(8) + Int_to_str(9);
    }
}
```

Возвращает ошибку:

```
public int Int_to_str(int i){
    ^
/Kata.java:3: error: ';' expected
    public int Int_to_str(int i){
                         ^
/Kata.java:3: error: ';' expected
    public int Int_to_str(int i){
```

Comment: Вас не смущает метод в методе?

Answer (score 3):

У вас метод в методе. Вынесите его и сделайте `static`.

К примеру:

```
public class Kata {

    private static int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

    public static String createPhoneNumber(int[] numbers) {

        return "(" + Int_to_str(0) + Int_to_str(1) + Int_to_str(2) + ") " +
                Int_to_str(3) + Int_to_str(4) + Int_to_str(5) + "-" +
                Int_to_str(6) + Int_to_str(7) + Int_to_str(8) + Int_to_str(9);
    }

    public static String Int_to_str(int i) {
        return Integer.toString(numbers[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(createPhoneNumber(numbers));
    }
}
```

Лишнее можно убрать оставить только методы. Код можно переписать намного лучше, но это тоже работает.